# Append values in pandas where value equals other value

Tags: python, pandas, date, if-statement, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
dfi = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Mauricio/Desktop/inflation.csv')
dfm = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Mauricio/Desktop/maturity.csv')
# equals the following
  observation_date  CPIAUCSL
0       1947-01-01     21.48
1       1947-02-01     21.62
2       1947-03-01     22.00
3       1947-04-01     22.00
4       1947-05-01     21.95
  observation_date  DGS10
0       1962-01-02   4.06
1       1962-01-03   4.03
2       1962-01-04   3.99
3       1962-01-05   4.02
4       1962-01-08   4.03
```

I created a copy as df doing the following:

```
df = dfi.copy(deep=True)
```

which returns an exact copy of dfi, **dfi** dates go by **month** and **dfm** dates go by **day**, I want to create a new column in df that everytime a date in dfi == a date in dfm, to append the DGS10 value in it.

I have this so far:

```
for date in df.observation_date:
    for date2 in dfm.observation_date:
        if date==date2:
            df['mat_rate'] = dfm['DGS10']

# this is what I get but dates do not match values
   observation_date  CPIAUCSL  mat_rate
0       1947-01-01     21.48      4.06
1       1947-02-01     21.62      4.03
2       1947-03-01     22.00      3.99
3       1947-04-01     22.00      4.02
4       1947-05-01     21.95      4.03
```

It works but does not append the dates where **date == date2** what can I do so it appends the values **where date equals date2 only**?
Thank you!

Comment: Uh, those dates aren't equal though, how are you still combining the rows?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ those are only the first 4 dates, the whole data set is 14000 entries, that's why it finds that date == date2 at some point in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date formats are inconsistent, convert them first:

```
dfi.observation_date = pd.to_datetime(dfi.observation_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
dfm.observation_date = pd.to_datetime(dfm.observation_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now, getting your result should be easy with a `merge`:

```
df = dfi.merge(dfm, on='observation_date')
```

Comment: Awesome! that did the work, you have a little mistake: dfm.observation_date = pd.to_datetime(dfm.observation_date, format='%Y-%d-%m')                                                                                        should be: dfm.observation_date = pd.to_datetime(dfm.observation_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')                                                                                         in case anyone else wants to use this as a solution as well

Comment: @MauricioCastaneda I thought the date formats of `dfi` and `dfm`  were different? You said `dfi` starts with day, and `dfm` starts with the month. Or are they the same?

Comment: @COLDSPEED they are the same, what I mean is that dfi is recorded monthly, and dfm is recorded daily, but both the same %Y-%m-%d format

Comment: @MAUCA You might not even need to datetime conversion now!.